# Are you able to assign a definition to each value in a tuple?

Tags: python-3.x, list, tuples, definition

I am not sure how to add definitions to values in a tuple.

I've searched various websites and Q & A on Stack Overflow but I couldn't find an answer

-

-

Comment: You should better explain what you're trying to do.

Comment: Do you mean a named tuple: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple

Comment: Im making a tuple about pizza flavours/types and in this tuple i want to give a description about what the pizza is like.. hope this is enough for u to understand

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be helpful if you explain what this is a part of, and if you supply some code.

Comment: You would need a dictionary for that

Comment: dictionarys have things and values for that thing

Comment: read about it here: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like what you are looking for is a dictionary.

This is an example:

```
dict = {"Pizza": "Tasty", "number": 2}
```

This apply's `Pizza` as `Tasty`, and `number` as `2`.